# SQL update statement to add a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-update

```
   public void InsertUserReputation()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("UPDATE u ");
    sb.Append(" SET u.Reputation = (u.Reputation + @Reputation)");//Problem is here u.Reputation is "Null" not 0... I think i need some if statement to check if it is a null and then update it to 0 and then add..what do you think?
    sb.Append(" FROM Users u");
    sb.Append(" INNER JOIN Comments c ON c.UsersID = u.UsersID");
    sb.Append(" WHERE c.CommentsID = @CommentsID");

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reputation", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 5;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommentsID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = commentID;  
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I want to add a reputation to the user of 5 points for the comment he leaves in the thread..but it fails to update why?/... commentID does get a value and so the reputation paramater

Comment: (you don't need a StringBuilder for that statement, btw - that is adding a tiny touch of overhead, but more importantly: it makes the code unnecessarily complex)

Comment: is `u.Reputation` null by any chance?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?  Or it runs, but no error?  More details, please.

Comment: The SQL looks good to me have you tried running SQLProfiler http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/ to see what the DB is actually running

Comment: just try to execute the query from sql

Comment: I dont get any errors... I allowed Reputation to be null..yeah..

Comment: @WithFlyingColors that is the problem as Marc Gravell said `NULL + 5`  will = NULL.  You need to start with 0 in your field

Comment: How do i write a statement to check if u.Reputation is null and then convert it to 0 or set it to 0

Comment: Why not just change the field to NOT allow NULLS and set the default value = 0

Comment: do mean the default value in  VS2010 (GENERAL) --> Default value or binding?!?!

Comment: How do you do that...set the default value to 0

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
SET u.Reputation = (u.Reputation + @Reputation)
```

into:

```
SET u.Reputation = COALESCE(u.Reputation,0) + @Reputation
```

so `NULL`s in `Reputation` field are changed into `0` before adding `@Reputation`.

---

Alternatively, you can keep your code if you first set all `NULL` values to `0` and then make the field `NOT NULL` using statement [**ALTER TABLE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx). Execute the following, once:

```
UPDATE Users
SET Reputation = 0
WHERE Reputation IS NULL ;

ALTER TABLE Users 
ALTER COLUMN Reputation NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sb.Append(" SET Reputation = (u.Reputation + @Reputation)");
```

edit: I missed your original note about u.Reputation possibly being Null. Try next:

```
sb.Append(" SET Reputation = (isnull(u.Reputation,0) + @Reputation)");
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Actually ypercube answer should give same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change

```
SET u.Reputation = (u.Reputation + @Reputation)
```

to

```
SET u.Reputation = COALESCE(u.Reputation + @Reputation, @Reputation, 0)
```

but all the existing answers well-address your needs

The only benefit the above offers is that, in the event @Reputation is also NULL, it still works.