# If and Null sql statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

UPDATE: Is this statement correct

```
  public void CheckReputationIfNull()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("DECLARE @isReputationNull int");
    sb.Append(" SET @isReputationNull=( SELECT Reputation");
    sb.Append(" FROM Users u");
    sb.Append(" INNER JOIN Comments c ON c.UsersID = u.UsersID");
    sb.Append(" WHERE c.CommentsID = @CommentsID)");

sb.Append(" BEGIN IF ( @isReputationNull IS NULL)");
sb.Append("UPDATE u ");
sb.Append(" SET Reputation = 0");
sb.Append(" FROM Users u");
sb.Append(" END");

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommentsID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = commentID;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISNULL is a function, so you can do:

```
ISNULL(MyColumn, 'alternative value')
```

What you want to do is:

```
IF (MyColumn IS NULL)
```

Which is checking if the column is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler, single statement, less prone to errors:

```sql
UPDATE Users SET Reputation = COALESCE(Reputation,0) WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

Or, update your table definition so that Reputation isn't nullable in the first place (and optionally, so that it defaults to 0)

---

Or, to combine it with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606520/problem-with-an-sql-update-statement) (I'm still not sure you shouldn't have just updated/amended that one), you could have:

```sql
UPDATE Users SET Reputation = COALESCE(Reputation,0) + @NewReputation
   WHERE UserID = (select UserID from Comments where CommentID = @CommentID)
```

Comment: +1 "[alter] your table definition so that `Reputation` isn't nullable"

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (@isReputationNull IS NULL)
BEGIN
...
END
```

You need a space between IS and NULL. Also BEGIN is after the IF statement

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 sb.Append(" IF @isReputationNull IS NULL BEGIN");
```

`ISNULL` - is a function in select clause, and you don't need it. Also you should move the `BEGIN` keyword after the `IF` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you need to move the BEGIN on the next line after the IF. The syntax for IF in SQL is:

```
DECLARE @test INT
SET @test = 1

IF (@test = 1) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'test is equal to one'
END
```

Secondly, you have not provided a WHERE condition in your update statement. If you execute your statement as it currently is, it will update the reputation for all users in the table, possibly causing you to lose data. If you are only looking to initialize the reputation for that specific user who posted the comment, you need to include a WHERE UserID = @UserID (you can populate this variable in the first query).

Also, if you heavily use parameterized queries, I would encourage you to create the queries directly in an SQL Editor first (such as Visual Studio with a data connection or SQL Server Management Studio). This will help you identify and fix any syntax errors before you add the statement to your code, since they become much harder to debug once you have converted them into a string in your code.

Comment: I am not saying that your query won't work. I was trying to point out that your query is correct only if you are trying to update the reputation for all users in your database. However, if you are trying to update the reputation for a single user (I don't know what your requirement is here), this query will cause you to overwrite data for all other users as well.